# Haskell String to List String split by whitespace

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am very new to Haskell, I have a problem, how to split given string into list of words.

example `"Hello world from haskell"` -> `["Hello","world","from","haskell"]`

thanks for your help

Comment: `words "Hello world from Haskell"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [*Hoogle*](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=String%20%2D%3E%20%5BString%5D) and search for example by signature. Since you want to convert a `String` to a list of `String`s, the signature is thus `String -> [String]`. The first matches are [**`lines :: String -> [String]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) and [**`words :: String -> [String]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words). Based on the name of the function, `words` is the right match.

As the documentation on `words` says:

> **`words :: String -> [String]`**
>
> `words` **breaks a string up into a list of words**, which were delimited
>   by white space.
>
> ```
> >>> words "Lorem ipsum\ndolor"
> ["Lorem","ipsum","dolor"]
> ```

This thus seems to be the function you are looking for. If we run this in `ghci`, we get the expected output:

```
Prelude> words "Hello world from haskell"
["Hello","world","from","haskell"]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
words :: String -> [String]
```

words breaks a string up into a list of words, which were delimited by white space.

```
>>> words "Lorem ipsum\ndolor"
["Lorem","ipsum","dolor"]
```

Reference: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#v:words